# CHADeMO protocol understanding

Tags: embedded, protocol

I want to know specification for CHADeMO standard,its a fast charging method for electric vehicle upto 400 kW preparing 900 kW on the map.I tried searching data for CHADeMO but just found above information.
Anyone can share their experience on how it works?

Comment: https://www.chademo.com/tag/standard/ has a "Members" tab with a "Join us" option. This is probably the best way to find out about future standards. Searching "chademo standard" finds plenty of other information including the names of current (IEC/IEEE) standards. I can only conclude you didn't search very hard.

Answer (score 1):

Know that Industrial standards are not usually free or easy to find and often behind a paywall.

But with keywords and Socratic learning methods, you can find what you need by this.

e.g. https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Allan-Miller-6/publication/319162700_Rapid_EV_Chargers_Implementation_of_a_Charger/links/5996027ca6fdcc35c6bfee96/Rapid-EV-Chargers-Implementation-of-a-Charger.pdf?origin=figuresDialog_download